# Pivot report with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pivot

I have 3 mysql tables like below:
table-01: company

```
id | comp_name | year
------------------------
 1 | Novartis  | 2015
 2 | Roche     | 2015
 3 | Glaxco    | 2015
```

table-02: product

```
id | fullname
 1 | Paracetamol
 2 | Eesomaprazol 
 3 | Phenobuterol
```

table-03: bid

```
id | comp_id | prod_id | rate | year
 1 |       1 |       1 |  2.0 | 2015
 2 |       1 |       2 |  4.2 | 2015
 3 |       1 |       3 |  2.3 | 2015
 4 |       2 |       1 |  3.0 | 2015
 5 |       2 |       2 |  4.0 | 2015
 6 |       2 |       3 |  2.5 | 2015
 7 |       3 |       1 |  2.3 | 2015
 8 |       3 |       2 |  4.5 | 2015
 9 |       3 |       3 |  2.8 | 2015
```

From the above three tables I want to get following summary table fetched by php:

```
fullname     | Novartis | Roche | Glaxco
Paracetamol  |      2.0 |   3.0 | 2.3
Eesomaprazol |      4.2 |   4.0 | 4.5 
Phenobuterol |      2.3 |   2.5 | 2.8
```

I don't have much idea about how to create a pivot report from php using MySQL table and prepared statement. Also, I have to achieve this from php end (not from SQL query of MySQL end).

I don't have any idea how to achieve this, although I know basic MySQL query and can get and fetch normal MySQL data. But if I can get a practical idea from the data of above three tables, I can go ahead from any large and complex data structure.

Comment: OK, omitted that clause

Answer (score 4):

You must dynamically generate columns to pivot, you can use this at mysql:

```
#1st part
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT CONCAT('sum(case when comp_name = ''', comp_name, ''' then rate else 0 end) as ',
                    replace(comp_name, ' ', ''))
)
INTO @sql
FROM company;

#2nd part
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT
  fullname,
  ', @sql, '
FROM bid
  JOIN product ON product.id = bid.prod_id
  JOIN company ON company.id = bid.comp_id
GROUP BY fullname');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

---

Explanation:

**#1st part**

This part generates SQL to sum rates and generate column headers, so in `@sql` you will have:

```
sum(case when comp_name = 'Novartis' then rate else 0 end) as Novartis,sum(case when comp_name = 'Roche' then rate else 0 end) as Roche,sum(case when comp_name = 'Glaxco' then rate else 0 end) as Glaxco
```

**#2nd part**

This part generate and execute main query, which generates output.

---

And output (for me):

```
+--------------+----------+-------+--------+
| fullname     | Novartis | Roche | Glaxco |
+--------------+----------+-------+--------+
| Eesomaprazol |      4.2 |     4 |    4.5 |
| Paracetamol  |        2 |     3 |    2.3 |
| Phenobuterol |      2.3 |   2.5 |    2.8 |
+--------------+----------+-------+--------+
```

---

PHP code (I suppose you are using PDO):

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$dbh->query("SET @sql = NULL");
$dbh->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT CONCAT('sum(case when comp_name = ''', comp_name, ''' then rate else 0 end) as ',
                    replace(comp_name, ' ', ''))
    )
    INTO @sql
    FROM company"
);
$dbh->query("SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT
      fullname,
      ', @sql, '
    FROM bid
      JOIN product ON product.id = bid.prod_id
      JOIN company ON company.id = bid.comp_id
    GROUP BY fullname')"
);
$dbh->query("PREPARE stmt FROM @sql");
$result = $dbh->query("EXECUTE stmt")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$dbh->query("DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt");

print_r($result);
```

And output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Eesomaprazol
            [Novartis] => 4.2
            [Roche] => 4
            [Glaxco] => 4.5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Paracetamol
            [Novartis] => 2
            [Roche] => 3
            [Glaxco] => 2.3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Phenobuterol
            [Novartis] => 2.3
            [Roche] => 2.5
            [Glaxco] => 2.8
        )

)
```

Variable `@sql` is visible in the current db connection, so you can use it.

Comment: I had +1 your answer. Just one thing you can ameliorate : use id instead of comp_name in your `case`, which will save the join on company in the second request. Also i am not sure of whether or not you should group by comp_name/id or filter by year... it depends of what op wants.i don't know

Comment: Yeep in `case` can be id column too, this depends how OP want to implement, but you have good point. About grouping, I don't know what result OP want, but now is simply to change.

Comment: Anyway, if only i could +2 your answer, i would have done it.

Comment: This isn't at all how I'd do it, but +1 for effort.

Comment: I have one question, how can I get the company name as column heading, because as the company name is in array key then I have to specify company name for fetching data from associative array. But let there are more companies or even the companies are dynamic, so I don't know all the names of the companies. If I want to fetch the data in html table, then how can I get the company names as column heading of that html table?